# How can I sort a Ruby array into a hash from a key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, hash, mongoid

I have a Ruby array which looks like:

```
[
     #<Share _id: 507fd5a8ab432a6a35000006, _type: nil, price: {"cents"=>25535, "currency_iso"=>"USD"}, company_id: "507fcdb8ab432ac733000001", user_id: "507fcb06ab432a7c2e000001">,
     #<Share _id: 507fd5a8ab432a6a35000007, _type: nil, price: {"cents"=>25535, "currency_iso"=>"USD"}, company_id: "507fcdb8ab432ac733000001", user_id: "507fcb06ab432a7c2e000002">
]
```

How could I sort it by the key `company.symbol` (which is a Mongoid relation, and present in every Share object), so it ends up into a hash like

```
{
    :appl => [#<Share _id: 507fd5a8ab432a6a35000006, _type: nil, price: {"cents"=>25535, "currency_iso"=>"USD"}, company_id: "507fcdb8ab432ac733000001", user_id: "507fcb06ab432a7c2e000001">]
    :msft => [#<Share _id: 507fd5a8ab432a6a35000007, _type: nil, price: {"cents"=>25535, "currency_iso"=>"USD"}, company_id: "507fcdb8ab432ac733000001", user_id: "507fcb06ab432a7c2e000002">]
}
```

where `aapl` and `msft` are company symbols available on a Share's `company.symbol`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I asked, but works as I wanted:

```
@companies = current_user.shares.map { |s| s.company }.uniq.each do |company|
    puts "#{company.name}: #{company.shares.map { |s| s if s.user == current_user and s.company == company }}"
    # this prints all the shares of every company
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {}
shares.each{ |share|
  hash[share.company.symbol] = [] unless hash[share.company.symbol]
  hash[share.company.symbol] << share
}
```